# BottomNavigationView strange inner view

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I try to add custom view for shadow above `BottomNavigationView`, but there is one problem.

`BottomNavigationView` has two indirect children - `BottomNavigationMenuView` and `View`. The latter `View` has width of 1dp and is shown above `BottomNavigationView`.
So it makes 1dp gap between `BottomNavigationView` and my custom shadow.

What is this `View` for and how can i avoid it?

Here is layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom_shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**P.S.** I had found, that strange View is in fact **inside** BottomNavigationView and there is no gap. So it doesnt' make a problem. Here is screenshot of layout inspector.
[image]
But still just interesting, what this View is?

Comment: can you add screenshot

Comment: Have updated post.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1dp gap perhaps a quick fix is setting `android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"` to basically "force" the View to move down by that difference. Do you have code for the indirect children? The source code for BottomNavigationView does not seem to make any use of the spare "View".

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.java